# Unable to str_replace space

Tags: php, str-replace, utf8-decode

I try to pull out the number string from google and clean it up.

```
<?php
$q="35 meter in inch";
$query = explode (" ",$q);  
$googleUrl="http://www.google.com/search?q=$query[0]+$query[1]+$query[2]+$query[3]";
$package = file_get_contents("$googleUrl");
$content = preg_replace('/.*<h2[^>]* style="font-size:138%"><b>|<\/b><\/h2>.*/si', "", $package) ;
$number = explode (" ",$content);
$result = str_replace(' ','',$number[3]);
echo $result;   
?>
```

however, the number i've got has a space. 
I tried to replace it with needles " " or "&nbsp ;". Or utf8_encode, decode $content. None of them works.

Comment: Please tell me you're not seriously doing this in production code. The conversion from meters to inches is not a difficult one (it's certainly easier than writing code to parse google's calculator results)

Comment: I imagine he wants to provide the API to convert between any X and any Y, not just meters to inches. I don't know why it wasn't treating the gap in numbers as a space [very odd quirk], but I think I found a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the solution to your problem, the best answer is to replace anything that is not a number or punctuation using preg_replace(); Try this:

```
<?php
$q="35 meter in inch";
$query = explode (" ",$q);  
$googleUrl="http://www.google.com/search?q=$query[0]+$query[1]+$query[2]+$query[3]";
$package = file_get_contents("$googleUrl");
$content = preg_replace('/.*<h2[^>]* style="font-size:138%"><b>|<\/b><\/h2>.*/si', "", $package) ;
$number = explode (" ",$content);
$result = preg_replace("/[^\d.]/", '', $number[3]);
echo $result;
?>
```

But you may want to look into using google.com/ig/calculator. It should save a lot on bandwidth and save you having to pull a full Google Results page and replace on it: http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=35%20meter%20in%20inch

```
<?php
$q="35 meter in inch";
$query = explode (" ",$q); 
$googleUrl="http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=$query[0]+$query[1]+$query[2]+$query[3]";
$content = file_get_contents("$googleUrl");
preg_match("/rhs:\s\"(.*)\",error/", $content, $number);
$num = explode(" ", $number[1]);
$num = preg_replace("/[^\d.]/", '', $num[0]);
echo $num;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The calculator one is so much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's not really a space, even though it looks like it. You could try replacing all `\w` with the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

hi the space before `<?php` tag it it there in your code too? then that might be giving the space check that!

Comment: Trim only removes whitespace on the edge of strings

Comment: iknow, how can you suppose the resulting string from google to have spaces in between!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a space you are trying to remove, it is  "à" that is not visible in browser. You can also check these things by using your php script by commandline. You can use html entities function and then replace according to that